# How to upload program to board using Arduino sketch ver 1.6?

Tags: uploading, sketch

I am having problems uploading my program. I have been using the verify button aka the "checkmark" to upload my programs. I assumed that this was the correct button but now I am having problems uploading. When I attempt to use the "upload" button I get the error "can not open device". What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this error code?

Comment: install the device drivers for your Arduino!
steps to follow are mention in arduino website!

Comment: It's possible the port or the board got changed, check the tools menu.

Comment: Check Tools->Board, Tools->Port, and Tools->Programmer

Comment: The "problem uploading to board" error message includes this link to arduino.cc troubleshooting guide: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting

Answer (score 2):

The checkmark button is used to compile your program (which "verifies" your code), but does not upload it to the board. The "arrow" button is used to compile and upload your program.

If you cannot connect to the device, make sure the correct COM port is selected on the Tools->Ports menu, and make sure you have the correct board selected on Tools->Board (usually an Arduino UNO).

If you have not installed the drivers yet, you will not have a port present for your Arduino. If that is the case, here is a great tutorial that will help you get everything installed and set up correctly: https://learn.adafruit.com/lesson-0-getting-started